# Eliminating subfolders to move all files into one folder

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a folder that contains 32 folders, each with several image files. I would like to move all of these image files into one main folder. I know how to do that manually, folder by folder. Is there an automated command-line way to do that? I have Crunchbang Waldorf, and usually use PCmanFM as a file manager.

Answer (score 3):

/*/ stands for directories.

`mv /path/from/*/*.jpg /path/main/`

Comment: Btw, mv will warn you for duplicated names, it will let you know which copied to main dir, then you may check directories whic duplicated and didn't copied. @яша's command will work better if images are in tenuous nested levels.

Comment: thank you, it worked. But to maintain the proper order of the image files, I would have to remove the first three characters of each filename. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

if all these images have one extension, for instance `.jpg`:

```
find /directory/You/Want/To/Search -name "*.jpg" -exec cp -t /destination/directory {} +
```

Note: just make sure that all these images have one unique name otherwise this command would break

**UPDATE:**

if you don't know what are the images extensions you could just do that one:

```
 find /directory/You/Want/To/Search -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\|jpeg\)" -exec cp -t /destination/directory {} +
```